# Does anything happen after the credits?

Tags: beacon

I downloaded [Beacon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28738/new-games-for-2011/28976#28976) and 15 minutes later, I'm contemplating my legacy sitting atop the barren red sand dune.

Is that it?  I sat there for several minutes and it didn't go to a menu.  The credits just showed up way down in the corner, did their stuff, and left me all alone on this post-apocalyptic planet.  I couldn't even figure out how to quit.  Escape didn't do anything.

Does anything happen after the credits in Beacon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's it.

That's the ending - it's a 15 minutes game after all, as stated in [your link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28738/new-games-for-2011/28976#28976). [image: Source: Me. Just finished the game as well.]

Edit: I've asked the developer who confirmed that that's really the end. [link](https://twitter.com/randomnine/status/808704155758063616)